# How to compare timestamps on multiple servers at the same time using a bash script

Tags: bash

I have 15 servers and I need to write a bash script that issues the command "time" to all of these servers at one to see if all of their timestamps match up. I am a novice at bash. How would I write this script?

Comment: Not really an answer, but, why don't you just run NTP on all the servers?  Then there will be no question as to them being in sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's good way to go.

Generally you should create a script which outputs the current server time, then you need to open that script remotely from the other servers and compare the results. The problem is that the script will need some time to load and process so the timestamp will be calculated with a delay.

Another option is to start a time server on one of your server so that the other servers will synchronize with it.

The last option, the easiest and most reasonable, is to run rdate or ntpdate command on each server so they will synchronize with the same time server.

Comment: +1 for "not a good way to go". What do you do if the timestamps don't match up - sync with NTP!